# Laravel 5 Polymorphic Relations Touch Parent Timestamp

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following models with polymorphic relationship

```
class Sector extends Model {
      public function image() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
      }
}

class Image extends Model {
    protected $touches = ['imageable'];

    public function imageable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I want to touch the parent (Sector) model's timestamps when updating the image of the sector. I have added the $touches variable on Image model.

But this is not working.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works.

```
class Sector extends Model {
    public function image() {
      return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}

class Image extends Model {
    protected $touches = ['sector'];

    public function imageable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function sector() {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Sector', 'imageable');
    }

}
```